# sklearn extract "sign of scorer" from GridSearch Object

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, make-scorer

I have a situation where I can [dynamically pass some scorers to a grid search object](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), either in the form of strings (=`accuracy`) as well as custom scorers, created [via `make_scorer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) where the parameter `greater_is_better` might be `True` or `False`. in other words, my scorers are best not always when they are the "greatest" value.

What I want to do is to *dynamically* extract the "sign" of my scorer from the object so that, when I know how to rank the scores (I know this is trivial if you do it "statically"), be it a pre-configured already defined metric ("accuracy") or a given scoring metric.

I tried to look inside the "core" code of the `grid search object` but to no avail. is there some attribute or property I can leverage?

Example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

def build_grid_1():
    cls_1 = GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid, scoring='accuracy')
    cls_1.fit(X, y)
    return cls_1

def build_grid_2():
    cls_1 = GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid, scoring=make_scorer(func, greater_is_better=False))
    cls_1.fit(X, y)
    return cls_1

def build_grid_3():
    cls_1 = GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid, scoring=make_scorer(func, greater_is_better=True))
    cls_1.fit(X, y)
    return cls_1

def gauge_scoring_sign(grid_search_class):
        return scorer_sign
gauge_scoring_sign(build_grid_1()) # 1
gauge_scoring_sign(build_grid_2()) # -1
gauge_scoring_sign(build_grid_3()) # 1
```

Comment: An example please?

Comment: added in the main topic

Comment: I don't think the search object knows anything about it. `make_scorer` take care of this by just taking the negative of its `func` when `greater_is_better=False`, and so the search is still maximizing the scores it sees.

Comment: actually it min/max according to waht greater_is_better is. inside the core code, the str objects are then turned into make_scorer objects with appropriate greater_is_better parameters. the problem is extracting this object. I need this because it would be a proxy for the loss function of the algorithm, which varies from estimator to estimator